# showing whether a set is open wrt to a metric topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

we have a metric space (M
, d) and subsets V ⊂ M decide whether V
is open
with respect to the metric topology. If possible find a continuous function f
: M → X so that
V = f
−1
(Y ) for some “obviously” open subset Y ⊂ X of a suitable topological space X you choose.

M1 = R
2
, d1((x, y),(a, b)) = |x − a| + |y − b|, V1 = {(x, y) ∈ R
| xy > 1}

so im not really sure how these proofs are supposed to be done but I think it probably has to do with xy>1 giving a restriction to the domain....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the restriction in the domain gives you a hint. In particular, if you define a funtion $f(x, y) = xy$, from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then this set is $f^{-1} (1, \infty)$, as the restriction on the domain is basically $f(x, y) > 1$. If you can show $f$ is continuous with respect to the metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (or indeed any other topology on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $(1, \infty)$ is an open set), then you are done.

Comment: so when putting the function f=xy into the distance function do we say d((xy,ab),(cd,ef)=|xy-cd|+|ab-ef|  ?

Comment: Not exactly. You should show that, given any $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $$d((x, y), (a, b) < \delta \implies |f(x, y) - f(a, b)| < \varepsilon.$$ It helps to use the fact that \begin{align*}|xy - ab| &= |xy - xb + xb - ab| \\ &\le |x||y - b| + |x - a||b| \\ &\le |x - a||y - b| + |a||y - b| + |x - a||b|.\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

On deciding openness of $V$:  Fix $(a,b) \in M_1$ with $a,b>0$ wlog.  We want to find $r$ such that $d_1((a,b), (x,y)) < r$ implies $xy >1$.  Set $r << \text{min}(b - 1/a, a - 1/b)$.  Geometrically, you can see that every $(x,y)$ inside the $M_1$-ball $B_r((a,b))$ is such that the deviation of $(x,y)$ from $(a,b)$ must be very small in each coordinate.

More precisely, $V$ is open with respect to the Euclidean metric, so there is a Euclidean ball at $(a,b)$ lying in $V$--but within this very ball, you can find an open $M_1$-ball if you consider for a minute the geometry of the $d_1$ metric (hint: diamonds are forever).

Comment: i understand it geometrically ( ive drawn about 50 versions of the situation by now XD) its more the formalism that im having trouble with, our teacher didnt explain how we are supposed to tackle questions like these.